# Is it possible to shorten my if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, show-hide

### The Questions of if/else statements and other alike codes

Hi, currently I am using this code to call an *if/else statement*, to add and/or remove the class ".hide" whenever the different tables are clicked on. This code is working all fine, no trouble with it at all.

**Example 1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Year_Table').click(function() {
        if ($('#Month_Table').hasClass("hide")) {
            $('#Month_Table').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#Month_Table').addClass('hide');
            $('#Day_Table').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

But what I am wondering about, is if there is anyway to make the code shorter? but with the same outcome. That the class is add or removed.

I had another question a few days ago, where a guy shortened my *if/else statement* to this code below. Thank you

**Example 2**

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var games_month  = 0;
    var month_games  = "Games";

    $("#Games_Month").html(games_month);

    $('#January').click(function(){ 
        $('#Games_Month').html(function(_, html) {
        return html === month_games ? games_month : month_games;
     });
});
```

The shortened code works perfectly too, but gives me a couple of question marks.
Now, what I would like to know is:

**1:
What is this type of code that was shortened for me? I mean, what is it called?**

I have been told it might be a *callback function.*

**2:
What is different from a standard if/else statement and the shortened code?**

is it the same, just cleaned up? or is there any important difference?

**3:
What does the different parts of the shortened code mean? what do they do?**

To me it just seem like another kind of an if/else statement?

**4:
is there any way to make such a code with classes instead of variables?**

Simply instead of changing the variable, I would like to add or remove the class ".hide" and is it possible to add and remove several classes within this function?

**5:
Is there any other ways to code an if/else statement or code which gives the same result?**

I am very new at using both javascript and jQuery, but I'm trying to learn as much as possible. I appreciate all the help I can get to understand all this, everything will help me getting further into my knowlegde of coding.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure your example 1 is working at all? You're never un-hiding #Day_Table.

Comment: Yes I have just excluded the complete code, so it wouldn't take up too much space, the #Month_Table and #Day_Table is nested tables of #Year_Table   of course you can not see that without the html to it.

Comment: It's just that the more symmetrical your code is, the easier it is to shorten.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Year_Table').click(function() {
    $('#Month_Table').toggleClass("hide");
    $('#Day_Table').toggleClass('hide');

  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='Year_Table'>click me</span>

<span id='Month_Table'>Month_Table</span>

<span id='Day_Table'>Day_Table</span>
```

Use `.toggleClass()`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your example 1 code using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Year_Table').click(function() {
        $('#Month_Table').toggleClass('hide');
        $('#Day_Table').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

And in your example 2, you are using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of if/else statement which takes three operands.

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```